# Is there a way to get the coordinates of a specific object/click in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to write a program where if I click, a circle is drawn on the pygame screen. If I click again, another circle is drawn as well as a line connecting it to the previous circle drawn. Is there any way to track the coordinates of where you last clicked?

ps. I want to create like a star constellation effect after many clicks (to help you visualize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a list for the mouse positions:

```py
points = []
```

Add the position to list when the mouse is clicked:

```py
if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if e.button == 1:
        points.append(e.pos)
```

Draw the points in a loop:

```py
for pos in points:
   draw.circle(screen,GREEN, pos, 10)
```

If there are at least 2 points, then the lines between the points can be drawn by [`pygame.draw.lines()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines):

```py
if len(points) > 1:
    draw.lines(screen, GREEN, False, points)
```

Based on your previous question, I suggest the following:

[image]

```py
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()
points = []

# Game Loop
while running:
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 1:
                points.append(e.pos) 
            if e.button == 3:      
                points = []

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if len(points) > 1:
        draw.lines(screen, GREEN, False, points)
    for pos in points:
        draw.circle(screen,GREEN, pos, 10)

    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)

quit()
```

---

Alternatively the clicked position can be stored (`prev_pos`) and used the next time, when the mouse is clicked to draw a line.
I do not recommend this, because you'll lose the information about the clicked positions:

```py
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()
prev_pos = None

# Game Loop
while running:
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 1:
                if prev_pos != None:
                    draw.line(screen, GREEN, prev_pos, e.pos)
                prev_pos = e.pos
                draw.circle(screen, GREEN, e.pos, 10)
            if e.button == 3:     
                prev_pos = None 
                screen.fill(BLACK))

    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)

quit()
```

Comment: @conyieie The concept is very, very basic. Anyway I've provided an alternative solution. But you have to store the information about the previous position click. It is only possible to retrieve the actual position of the cursor. The system does not track the mouse positions history for you. Anyway I've explained the solution. You should try to understand it. The basic concept is, that the entire scene is redrawn in every frame. That will allow advanced concepts, like manipulation or undo/redo.

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean if prev_pos:  ? I thought that if statements had to have some kind of condition or something. Like if prev_pos == 4:  How does it work if there is nothing to compare it to?

Comment: @conyieie  `if prev_pos:` is the same as `if prev_pos != None:`. Note `prev_pos` is initialized by `None`. At the 1st click you cannot draw a line, because there is no _previous_ point.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will solve your problem:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html

" pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    get the mouse cursor position
    get_pos() -> (x, y)

```
Returns the X and Y position of the mouse cursor. The position is relative to the top-left corner of the display. The cursor position can be located outside of the display window, but is always constrained to the screen."
```

You can use  `pygame.draw.circle()` to draw a circle with a center at the point where the mouse is, and a polygon or lines if you'd like to connect them.

I hope this helps